# Blazor @onmousedown doesn't recognize long press

Tags: blazor

I want my program so differentiate between a short and long press. When pressing short (clicking) it works but when I keep the mouse down the @onmousedown is never called. Why is that?

```
<li @onmousedown="MouseDown" @onmouseup="MouseUp">
  ...
</li>


DateTime mouseDownTme;
void MouseDown()
{
    mouseDownTme = DateTime.UtcNow;
}
void MouseUp()
{
    long milliseconds = (DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - mouseDownTme.Ticks) / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
    if (milliseconds > 400)
    {
        //long press
        Console.WriteLine("long press");
    }
    else
    {
        //short press
        Console.WriteLine("short press");
    }
}
```

---

Edit:
This code works. There real problem was I was trying to do this in .NET MAUI Blazor. I did also test it in a normal blazor environment but it seems I made a mistake there since testing it again proved to work. Does anyone know where I can reoprt this issue to .NET MAUI Blazor?

Comment: Can you try to use @inject IJSRuntime with onmouseup !

Comment: It's the same thing. No difference with js

Comment: works ok for me : https://blazorrepl.com/repl/cFFEErPw33KHdP6607

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `@onmousedown` and  `@onmouseup`:

```
//Code behinde
private DateTime time1 { get; set; }
private DateTime time2 { get; set; }

<li @onmousedown="() => { time1 = DateTime.Now; }"
    @onmouseup="() => { time2 = DateTime.Now; }">
   Click me
</li>
@if ((time1.Ticks - time2.Ticks)/ TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond > 400)
     {
        <p>Long press</p>
     }
else
     {
       <p>short press</p>
     }
```

Comment: how is this any diffferent than what I did? This is not working that's the point. Because @onmouseup is not being triggered.

Comment: I tested, it works fine, I think that you have another problem

Answer (score 3):

you should use `OnPointerDown` and `OnPointerUp` which works for both Touch and Mouse ;)

[Full Sample in GitHub](https://gist.github.com/mhrastegari/e9489414ee0129a4d405ef6ffe587db5)

Answer (score 1):

Since I had the same issue using MAUI Blazor and I finally found a solution for me:

I had some code like this to draw on a canvas element:

```
<canvas @onpointerdown=this.OnPointerDown @onpointerout=this.OnPointerOut @onpointerup=this.OnPointerUp @onpointermove =this.OnPointerMove>
```

onpointerdown and onpointermove fired once, onpointerup only on a "fast click" without pressing longer. When using this code in a Blazor Server App everything worked fine.

It seems like other touch-events (like scroll or zoom?) trigger when pressing longer.

Finally I added following CSS to the canvas

```
touch-action:none;
```

ending up with code like this:

```
<canvas style="touch-action:none;" @onpointerdown=this.OnPointerDown @onpointerout=this.OnPointerOut @onpointerup=this.OnPointerUp @onpointermove =this.OnPointerMove>
```

And this just works fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a package for `onlongpress` so give it a try:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kebechet.Blazor.EventHandlers.LongPress/1.0.0-preview1

docs:
https://github.com/Kebechet/Blazor.EventHandlers.LongPress